# Adding a date/time service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I'm trying to set up a very basic service in Angular 2. The goal is to display the current date and time when a user clicks a button. When I use the code below, I get the following error:

`Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.whatTime is not a function`

Time Component:

```
@Component({
    template: `
      <h1>Time Test</h1>
      <button (click) = "whatTime()">Time</button>
      <h2>{{now}}</h2>
         `
})

    export class TimeComponent {
      now = Date();
      constructor(public timeService: TimeService) {
        this.now = timeService.whatTime();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
    export class TimeService {

      whatTime() {
      return new Date();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/t5m6MO?p=preview)

```
<button (click) = "now = timeService.whatTime()">Time</button>
```

but it might produce an devmode error.

A better way would be to add an `Observable` to the service that notifies about time changes in an predefined interval

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeService {

  constructor() {
    this.whatTime = Observable.interval(1000).map(x => new Date()).share();
  }
}
```

```
<!-- <button (click) = "whatTime()">Time</button> -->
  <h2>{{timeService?.whatTime | async}}</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I like the idea of using an `Observable`. But I'm getting a `Cannot have a pipe in an action expression` when I use the code above.

Comment: I updated my answer. My 2nd example always updates the time by itself. This might not be what you want though. See also https://plnkr.co/edit/yHxniL?p=preview

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but not exactly what I'm trying to do. I'd like the click to trigger the date/time.

Comment: That's what the first example in my answer shows. Does it not work?

Comment: My apologies for the delayed response. No, unfortunately, the first example still isn't working for me.

Comment: I added a Plunker link above the first example and updated the code of the first example.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found that [@günter-zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)'s observable-based solution takes a little while to load up (atleast in plnkr) ... haven't done official performance tests but ....

Here is a simple way to make realtime clock without using rxjs.

( See [Plunker of this working over here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PFOvjoqyGltsTig494q7?p=preview) )

You can use it in your template like so:

```html
<p>{{ now }}</p>

<!-- OR something like  -->

<h2>{{ now |  date:'yMMMdjms'  }}</h2>
```

Here is the component class definition:

```js
class ClockComponent {
  interval;

  now = new Date();

  constructor(){
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> { 
      this.now = new Date() ;

    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

}
```

That's it!